# iterated cross validation - concept

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, random-forest

I am comparing two classification methods: random forest and logistic regression for 10 000 sample with 150 bads (multiplied to 1500 bads).
I made cross validation with 5 folds and repeated it 10 times. For every cross validation i compute Gini-value.

Now i want to plot only 1 boxplot (gini value) for each method. Is it better to make a boxplot from every element (5 in each cross validation multiplied by 10 iters = 50 elements) or plot boxplot for median from each cross validation (10 elements)?